# Headlines in Beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

In Beamer presentation on one page I would like to get rid of headline. I would prefer to leave the background but get rid of the names of sections and subsections. How is it possible to do this?

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{top}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{bottom}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
} \mode <all>
```

Comment: Have you tried `\begin{frame}[plain]`?

Comment: As I explain in my answer, to suppress only the information about sections and subsections but keeping all the other elements (color boxes, etc.) we need information about the specific definition for the actual `headline` template that you are using. Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to suppress the complete headline, you can locally redefine the `headline` template to be empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{frame}
test frame with empty headline
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you only want to suppress the navigation information for sections and subsections, some more work is needed; you need to redefine the `headline` template as  defined in the outer theme used. For example, using the given `headline` template one can define a command, say `\nosecinhead`, to suppress the navigation bars from the headline for some frame(s); to use this command all you have to do is to say

```
\begingroup
\nosecinhead
```

right *before* `\begin{frame}`, and then

```
\endgroup
```

right *after* `\end{frame}`, as the following example illustrates (I assume that the `top` and `bottom` colors have been defined somewhere; I provided some *ad hoc* just for the example):

```
\documentclass[svgnames,x11names]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{top}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{bottom}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}

\newcommand\nosecinhead{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{top}
    \vskip2pt\mbox{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{bottom}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\begingroup
\nosecinhead
\begin{frame}
test frame with modified headline
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer the second solution (the one with more work). I edited my question with headline of my work. Would you know how to do modify it for my case?

Comment: @Laura I updated my answer providing the necessary code.

Comment: @Gonzola: It's almost what it should be only the white thin line above the two lines should be away and I woul like to add a line under two lines with \setbeamercolor{lower
separation line head}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}

Comment: @Laura I updated my answer. Please notice that in my example there's no white thin line; if this line appears in your document, something else must be going on with your settings and the information you provided is not enough to detect the problem. You could try playing by adding `\vspace*{<length>}` in an appropriate place in the definition of the `\nosecinhead` command and see if this helps you to get rid of that line.

Comment: @Gonzola: it's perfect now.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{How to use Beamer}
\subtitle{from novice to professional}
\author{Aggresive User}
\date{\today}
\institute{\TeX\ User Group}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
What is your next question \scalebox{10}{\bf ?}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\end{document}
```