# Leave out headline but keep a solid header background color

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I'm looking for some commands in order to set the beamercolor of my headline to grey. I don't want a headline. But if I left it out, the background stays white even if I use `\setbeamercolor{header}`...

I think we have to change the `\newenvironment{withoutheadline}...` but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[serif,xcolor=dvipsnames, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\input{example_media/Warsaw_Headline}
\usecolortheme{whale}
%\makeatletter
%\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
%\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
%}{}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{ddd}
\subsection{jjjj}
\subsection{sjsj}
\frame{hi}
%\begin{withoutheadline}
{
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=darkgray}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\color{black}}
\begin{frame}
\Large \color[rgb]{1,1,1}Thank you for your attention!
\end{frame}
}
%\end{withoutheadline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68834/headlines-in-beamer to see if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't understand your problem. You practically already solved.
You haven't a theme with headline, if you use a theme with headline, like in my code below, you will see that your environment works!

```
\documentclass[serif,xcolor=dvipsnames, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
\def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
}{}
\makeatother

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\begin{document}
\begin{withoutheadline}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=darkgray}
\begin{frame}{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}Frame Title without Headline}
\Large \color[rgb]{1,1,1}Thank you for your attention!
\end{frame}
\end{withoutheadline}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=darkgray}
\begin{frame}{\color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5}Frame Title with Headline}
\Large \color[rgb]{1,1,1}Thank you for your attention!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit cleaner: `\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}}{}`. So this doesn't need `\makatletter...\makeatother`

Comment: With my code below I couldn't get rid of background color (white/empty) when I use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`  or the `\newenvironment{withoutheadline}`.  But why isn't _Warsaw_ a theme with headline? There appears a headline when I use `\section`s and `\subsection`s.