# Removing the watermark/shadow of the palette title in Beamer

Tags: beamer, watermark, shadows

I would like to remove the title watermark/shadow from the title palette on the first page and the last page of Beamer. Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title[November 2019]{Removing the watermark}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Removing the watermark}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{}{}

Removing the watermark

\end{frame}

\include{help-thanks}

\end{document}
```

Being the thanks.tex:

```
\section{}

\begin{frame}

\centering
Thanks!

\end{frame}
```

Whose result is as follow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I would like to remove the title shadow from the title palette on the first page and the last page of Beamer as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: Please clarify where exactly you would like to remove teh shadow. In your question, you write " on the first page and the last page", on the screenshots, however, there are red arrows on all slides.

Comment: Hello @leandriis! It is only on the first and last page. I put a red arrow on all of them to demonstrate that I want the middle page to continue showing the section title.

Comment: So, do you want to only remove the shadow underneath the black/blue line or do you also want to remove the black/blue lines itself on the first and last slide? What should happen to the text on that line? Also remove it? Please clarify.

Comment: Having had a closer look at the screensots you posted, it seems as if you just wanted to remove the section title in the black header bar. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @leandriis! That's right! I just want to remove the section title from the black header bar. The black / blue bars should remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locally redefine the templates used, see for more examples this Q&A: [Headlines in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68834/33413).

For your case this should do:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title[November 2019]{Title: Removing the watermark}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\section{Section: Removing the watermark}
\begin{frame}
Normal text: Removing the watermark
\end{frame}

% etc. 
\end{document}
```

---

For more frequent uses I'd recommend defining a new environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title[November 2019]{Title: Removing the watermark}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\date{November 2019}

\newenvironment{headless}
  {%
    \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{}
    \begin{frame}
  }{%
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{headless}
\maketitle
\end{headless}

\section{Section: Removing the watermark}
\begin{frame}
Normal text: Removing the watermark
\end{frame}

% etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Setting a new environment worked very well for me!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are satisfied with the newly defined `\hidesectiontitles` command as shown in the following MWE. If you want to use it on the title frame, make sure, you enclose both commands in a set of `{}`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[November 2019]{Removing the watermark}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\date{November 2019}


\newcommand{\hidesectiontitles}{\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black}
                                \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=black}
                                \setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{parent=palette quaternary}
                                \setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{parent=palette primary}}

\begin{document}

{\hidesectiontitles
\maketitle}

\section{Removing the watermark}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}{}
Removing the watermark
\end{frame}

\hidesectiontitles
\begin{frame}
\centering
Thanks!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Probably not the most elegant solution, but with redefining `\pgfdeclareverticalshading` as shown in the following example, you can remove the shadow under the frametitle on all frames of your presentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(0pt)=(bg)}
}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[November 2019]{Removing the watermark}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\date{November 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Removing the watermark}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}{}
Removing the watermark
\end{frame}

\section{}

\begin{frame}
\centering
Thanks!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```